# can't understand how this function (getCache) works in PHP

Tags: php

hope that someone helps me understand this:

```
function getCache($key, $timeout = 30) {
    $contents = false;
    if (MEMCACHE <> 0) {
         global $memcache;
         $contents = $memcache->get($key);
     }
    if (empty($contents)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $contents;
}

if($onlineFrnds = getCache($userid, 30)){
//do stuff
}
```

I didn't write this code, it's in code I am trying to modify (and so to understand).

What I can't explain is the call of setCache with 30 and why it is set again with $timeout = 30. Morevoer the $timeout is not used in the function.
What happens is that the if condition evaluates to true if 30 seconds are passed.

Comment: the $timeout=30 is a default if nothing is passed on the function call

Comment: One is not calling the other, unless we're missing something. setCache() does not call getCache()

Comment: This is a cache function, the mechanism is simple, it try to get the cache contents, if no cache, we set it an return it.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, setCache had to be getCache, I edited the code

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be found in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

Comment: my question is not caused by typographical error: I didn't know about default parameter, now clear to me. But still I don't understand how it checks the 30 seconds and the outside function IF condition is true or false if 30 seconds are passed or not.

Answer (score 7):

`$timeout = 30` is a default parameter. This means if you don't provide it the parameter will use the value `30`.

Here's a little demo to show you how it works:

```
function demo($timeout = 30) {
    return $timeout;
}

echo demo(); // 30
echo demo(15); //15
```

---

It looks like the `$timeout` was meant to be used to expire the cache but was never used.

Comment: Yep, it's very common to set a new TTL for something in cache when you get a hit. It's thinking "Okay, this hit, must be important, I'm going to keep it for another nnnn seconds" - it just wasn't implemented. Also useful if you want it to return false if something was _about_ to expire in nnn seconds.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing there is the definition of an *optional parameter*.

Let's see, example... ah, [here we go (http://php.net/trim)](http://php.net/trim)

> string trim ( string $str [, string $character_mask = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] )

Do you see there, how the `$character_mask` parameter is "defined" in the function signature? What that means is that, if you do not pass it a parameter there, then it will default to that.

Now, in your code, it's being set to `30` and `30` is the default. That's fine, it means that it's not dependent on the default (because it could, in theory, change, so it will always be `30` for this call).

Now, as for it not being used, that seems more like a design flaw in the code itself, or possible a Copy/Paste/Derp™, in which the function signature was copied from another function and then not edited. It makes no significant difference.